# jsf with jsf composite component outputs <html> tag 2 times

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Good day!

In my project I have a JSF custom component
File `ProjectRoot/web/resources/foo/bar.html`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"      
      xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="title"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h1>#{cc.attrs.title}</h1>
        <h:outputText value="foo"/>
    </composite:implementation>

</html>
```

And then I use my component in another JSF-page. 
File `ProjectRoot/web/index.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:foo="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/foo"
      >

    <f:view>
        <h:head>
            <title>JSFGantt</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <foo:bar title="title"/>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>

</html>
```

I open page sources in my browser after deploying my app and I see this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
            <title>JSFGantt</title></head><body><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <h1>title</h1>foo

</html></body>
```

So why JSF output `<html>` tag for each composite component on page (2 times in this case)? And how to force JSF show only one `<html>` per page?

P.S. Of course my component more complicated, this is just an example.
P.P.S. I use Netbeans as IDE and Glassfish 4 as Application Server. I tried another IDE, but in IntellijIdea I have some problem.

Comment: I tried this with Mojarra 2.2.2 in a Maven based project running on Tomcat and it works fine without the additional html tag. Maybe there is a bug in the Mojarra version bundled with Glassfish 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace URL's are not correct. In bar.xhtml use:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
```

and for your index.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:foo="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/foo">
```

Comment: That's what the docs say, but I have a JSF 2.2 project up and running and when I change the namespaces to the new ones I have the same problem as the poster. The old ones still work fine.

Comment: I think there was in bug in early 2.2 versions of Mojarra.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. But some sources recommends use `http://xmlns.jcp.org/...` instead `http://java.sun.com/...`. They said that second variant is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, I would use the new ones if possible (starting with `http://xmlns.jcp`). The old ones might be removed in the future (for now using the old ones should cause no trouble). To make the new ones work, you should upgrade Mojarra to a current version.